# How to use js variables in "old" MUI syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have recently revised my very old app where styling with MUI is like this

```
const filterStyle = {
    width: "320px !important",
    margin: "0 auto",
    "@media(maxWidth: 780px)": {
        width: "80%",
    },
};
```

and this object is consumed in sx like this

```
<Stack
            role="form"
            sx={{ ...filterStyle }}
            direction="row"
            spacing={2}
            
        >
```

I want to use variable breakpoint VERY_SMALL_BREAKPOINT -without using theme - like this:

```
const filterStyle = {
    width: "320px !important",
    margin: "0 auto",
    "@media(maxWidth: VERY_SMALL_BREAKPOINT)": {
        width: "80%",
    },
};
```

Obviously, it does not work; but is there a way to make it work? I would not use .matches etc, would rather solve the issue with code similar to existing one. Is that possible?